# Guice - No implementation was bound (for List<String>)

Tags: java, guice

I am trying to bind an instance of List when a List is annotated with specific annotation.

I tried using Instance Binding and Provider methods, but I keep getting the error.

Here is my @Provides method and configure()

```
@Provides @Named("Regions")
public List<String> getRegions() {
    return AppConfig.findVector("Regions"); //this would return a Vector<String>
}

@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(List.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Regions")).to(Vector.class);
}
```

Here's how I try to fetch the instance -

```
List<String> regions = injector.getInstance(Key.get(List.class, Names.named("Regions")));
```

This is the error that I get

```
com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for java.util.List annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=Regions) was bound.
while locating java.util.List annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=Regions)
```

Comment: can you share the code from your ServiceModule where you might have `bind` the field?

Comment: @nullpointer I have added the `configure()` method as well. That is all I have in my ServiceModule

Answer (score 7):

To Guice, a `List` is different from a `List<String>`, and a `@Named("Regions") List` is different from a `@Named("Regions") List<String>`.

Use a `new TypeLiteral<List<String>>() {}` (N.B. generically-typed anonymous inner class, as that is necessary to get non-erased generics at runtime) in your `Key.get` to request a generic type from Guice.

Separately, your `bind` statement isn't helping anything, and can be removed. You'll need to manually convert your Vector into a List in your @Provides method, but bind won't help you do that.